# Redirect to related list sub tab on Lightning Page

Tags: related-list, hyperlink

I have a scenario to redirect my users upon a Hypelink field click.

We should redirect the user to a related list sub tab instead of the details tab? I've url's for related list but it would open the whole page instead of a sub tab.

Given that the url is same for an objects detail page or related list sub tab, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a function for this?

Comment: I'm using a url formula field but its redirecting to details tab instaed of related list

Comment: This would be so useful, esp when you are adding related records and want to return to the parent and see the Related records!